# What's wrong with my code? (from ACM problems)

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to solve the Q272: TeX Quotes

This is the question's links:
chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://onlinejudge.org/external/2/272.pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zzBE.jpg)

And below is my code:

```
while True:
    try:
        strings = input()
        string=[]
        t=-1
        for a in strings:
            string.append(a)
        for abcd in string:
            if abcd == '''"''':
                t=t+1
                if t%2==0:
                    string[string.index(abcd)] = '``'
                else:
                    string[string.index(abcd)] = """''"""
        output=''.join(string)
        print(output)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

It's correct when I'm testing but the onlinejudge keep sending me emails that say I got wrong answers!!!
Please help me find out the problems.

Comment: Can you summarize the question here?

Comment: This code does not work properly on the sample provided in the problem statement.

Comment: `string.index(abcd)` is going to give you the index of the first instance of that character in the string, which may not be the index your loop is currently working on.  Use `for idx, abcd in enumerate(string):` to actually get the index of the loop.

Comment: With the same clicks and movements you made to take that screenshot and cut it you coudldve have copied and pasted the text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your code outputs:

```
``To be or not to be,'' quoth the Bard, ``that
is the question``.
The programming contestant replied: ``I must disagree.
To `C' or not to `C', that is The Question!``
```

when it should output:

```
``To be or not to be,'' quoth the Bard, ``that
is the question''.
The programming contestant replied: ``I must disagree.
To `C' or not to `C', that is The Question!''
```

So, no, it's not correct.

Besides, it's likely that the input must go all at once and the output should come when the EOF is detected, not line by line, but that's just my assumption.